# Getting gdb to display current thread when stepping

Tags: gdb

I'm using the command like interface to gdb and have set a breakpoint in multi-threaded code.

All I want is for it to display some sort of ID for the current thread so I know when I'm looking at a different thread.

I know about the `thread` command, but don't want to type it in every single time.

I also know about setting breakpoints that fire only on a particular thread, but that's not what I want.

Is there a way to get gdb to just print the ID of the current thread while stepping through code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Python-enabled gdb, you can do it with "set extended-prompt".

Comment: How do I know if I have a python enabled gdb?

Comment: @C, Just type: `set extended-prompt (gdb,thread:\t)`. If `gdb` accept this command it will print the thread number